# deserialize returns empty inner list right after serialize

Tags: c#, serialization

I have class TestCase which contains list of results:

```
[XmlRoot("TestCase")]
public class TestCase
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Results", typeof(List<TestCaseResult>))]
    public List<TestCaseResult> Results
    {
        get
        {
            return results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            results = value;
        }
    }
```

TestCaseResult looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("TestCaseResult")]
public class TestCaseResult
{
    [XmlElement("HtmlPath")]
    public string HtmlPath { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FailedCommand")]
    public string FailedCommand { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

what I do, is I collect testcases into List and then I'm serializing it.
I serialize whole list, right after that I deserialize it and List is empty. but results are stored in xml correctly. what am I doing wrong?

edit: added setter to TestCase.Results, but it did not help, problem is still there. Results are deserialized empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `Results` is empty than you need setter for this property

```
[XmlElement("Results", typeof(List<TestCaseResult>))]
public List<TestCaseResult> Results
{
    get
    {
        return results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        results = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not help, Results is still empty even after I added setter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem was with the actual getter, which returned sorted list.

probably when deserializing, framework asks for List and then fills it, when I ordered the list I actually created new one, so the original was never filled.